# asp.net core Identity cookie is larger than 4096 characters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm using Identity to authenticate users in my Asp.Net Core SPA application. The code for login is this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginModel loginModel)
{
  var user =
      await userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginModel.Name);
  if (user != null)
  {
    await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    if ((await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, loginModel.Password, loginModel.RememberMe, false)).Succeeded)
    {
      return Json(true);
    }
  }
  return Json(-1);
}
```

and the code part related to identity in my startup.cs file is:

```
  services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole<int>>(opts =>
  {
    opts.Password.RequiredLength = 1;
    opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    opts.Password.RequireDigit = false;
  })
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SampleAppContext>()
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

The user class is defined like this:

```
public class User: IdentityUser<int>
{
    public List<Access> AccessList { get; set; }
    public int? PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Person and Access are two other classes. The problem is, when my app tries to authenticate users and set auth cookies, this warning pops up in devTools and browser fails to store the cookie with error "Set-Cookie header is ignored in response from url: http://localhost:5000/api/Account/Login. Cookie length should be less than or equal to 4096 characters.":

[Cookie is too big error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrWHM.png)

Do you have any idea why auth cookie is so big?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @runia I'm not sure really, but I think I ended up merging Person into User (instead of having a reference) and that solved the problem.